# Is there an alternative syntax to Laravel's DB::raw() for querying against a column value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've got two integer fields `sent` and `limit`

I want to do the following.

```
$overdrawn = Store::select('id')
->where('status', '=', 'active')
->where('sent', '>=', 'limit')
->get();
```

Obviously this looks for columns where the integer value of `sent` is greater than or equal to the string 'limit' which is not the desired behaviour.

I know I can pass `DB::raw('limit')` but wondered if there's an alternative syntax that would achieve the same results?

since some people seem confused about the SQL I want to execute it is as follows.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `store` where `status` = 'active' and `sent` > `limit`;
```

Comment: "limit' which is not the desired behavior." what is the desired behavior?

Comment: limit is an integer not the string of the column name. Maybe that wasn't clear enough but it is right there in the question.

Comment: yeah its not clear to me at all, if you want to check against an integer, then put the integer in there. ->where('sent', '>=', '5')

Comment: `->where('sent', '>=', DB::raw('limit'))` seems great - don't know if there is something else you could try with query builder..

Comment: @ATechGuy the integer to check against is stored in the DB I'm querying.

Comment: As far as I know, that's the only way to go about it. You'll probably also need to put the backticks around `limit` because it's a reserved word.

Comment: Why don't you show us the SQL query you want to run via Eloquent? The question / your comments are not clear

Comment: @AlexG. Done, although I'm leaning towards there not being an alternative solution as suggested in the comments by the two people who could understadn the question.